# weblogic server did not start properly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, server-side, myeclipse, weblogic8.x

Whenever running the weblogic server getting the error.

```
:\bea8_1_3\user_projects\domains\snap\snap\config.xml not found

No config.xml was found.
Would you like the server to create a default configuration and boot? (y/n): y
<Feb 3, 2011 5:51:08 PM EST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090115> <Created new Administrative User weblogic> 
For confirmation, please re-enter password required to boot WebLogic server:
Passwords do not match.
For confirmation, please re-enter password required to boot WebLogic server:
***************************************************************************
The WebLogic Server did not start up properly.
Exception raised: 'weblogic.management.configuration.ConfigurationException: Passwords do not match, unable to generate default configuration, please try again.'
Reason: weblogic.management.configuration.ConfigurationException: Passwords do not match, unable to generate default configuration, please try again.
***************************************************************************
```

Please suggest me , how to solv this error.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the correct password when trying to boot the WebLogic server, or create a config.xml configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, are you using the weblogic console or any IDE?

You can try to go the path indicated in your code: 
**"\ bea8_1_3 \ user_projects \ domains \ snap \ snap \ config.xml"**
and see if you have any config.xml. Otherwise you have you have to install a new domain.

Or go to bin folder, in your first snap directory and do the commando to startWeblogic.sh (to Linux or startWebLogic.cmd to Windows), because weblogic build a new config.xml if you don't have any in that folder.

My last recourse is for you to go in pending folder and copy the config.xml file and paste in confg directory in first "snap."